# How to make archive file with checksum like tar.md5 or tar.gz.md5?

Tags: hashsum, archive

How can I add checksum information to a TAR archive, as in

- `file.tar` -> `file.tar.md5` or
- `file.tar.gz` -> `file.tar.gz.md5`

I have searched everywhere but there is no guide or app about it. I need this to be able to automatically check for integrity.

Comment: md5sum... sha256sum... etc...just redirect the output. See the manuals for details.

Answer (score 1):

these files aren't "archives with checksums"; a.tar.md5 is just the checksum of a.tar, written to a file:

```
md5sum a.tar > a.tar.md5
```

You can check this very easily: put a.tar and a.tar.md5 in the same directory and run

```
md5sum --check a.tar.md5
```

Note that MD5 is **heavily** deprecated as checksum, as there's very many collisions, and it's **very easy** to craft a file that's different, but has the same MD5 checksum ([which means that MD5 is useless to prove that a file has not been modified intentionally](https://speakerdeck.com/ange/kill-md5)).

Use SHA-256 instead! The commands work exactly the same, just that you use `sha256sum` instead of `md5sum`.

Comment: thanks, please example of sha256, will it form a.tar.sha?

Comment: the file name is up to you to  define. It can be anything you want.

Comment: oh I tried, but your way produces 1 txt file containing hash code, that's not what I want to ask. I want to know how to make file like samsung stock rom with md5 hash "extension built in". like AP_XXX.tar.md5 or anything else like filetar.gz.md5...

Comment: This is not something standard.. Usually files with names like that are created like I described above. You'll need to tell us more about that file format - we can't know it.

Comment: If you have used a samsung phone, you probably know. It is stock rom file to flash via odin uncompressed tar format tar.md5 with built in md5 hash, the app will checksum the file and compare with the built in md5 hash given.

Comment: sorry, I don't have a samsung phone, I have no idea what odin is (other than a god of Norse mythology); that's not a file type description. Please link to something that actually describes the structure of that file.